# I'm trying to install npm package html2json but while installing getting error in windows

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I have updated npm and node both but it was not working.
I have searched for solution but not getting any solution.
Can anyone help me to solve my problem?
I tried all this mentioned below

```
npm -v
output: 3.10.10
node -v
output: v6.11.3
npm config get registry
output: https://registry.npmjs.org/
npm cache clean
```

While installing package I'm getting this error:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "F:\\ProgramFiles\\nodejs\\node.exe" "F:\\ProgramFiles\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "html2json"
npm ERR! node v6.11.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ENOSELF

npm ERR! Refusing to install html2json as a dependency of itself
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     E:\Html Parsing using node\html2json\npm-debug.log
```

Help needed.
Thank You

Comment: Make sure that your "name" is not the same as any of your dependencies.

Comment: Thanx alot for your help it worked. Actually I'm new to node.

Comment: Nice. your name property in packgae.json should not match any other dependency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the name of your npm project also `html2json`? That's the problem that was encountered on [this blog](http://thisdavej.com/node-newbie-error-npm-refusing-to-install-package-as-a-dependency-of-itself/). It seems to confuse Node when your project name is identical to a dependency package name.

Comment: Awesome, can you mark this as the answer? Thanks :)

Comment: Sure I'm trying mark this s answer but it is showing you can mark this as answer after 7min.